# Ubuntu 14.04 dualBox Windows 7

Tags: dual-boot

I had Windows 7 installed . Then I install ubuntu 14.04 (separated partition). but i cant have the liste of availbale OS in the HDD , so the PC start Win7 ! Any solution pliz ?

Answer (score 0):

There are many possible reasons for this. For instance, if your computer is using BIOS, you have to make sure, that the disc selected as boot device in BIOS setup, and the device you installed the Ubuntu Bootloader (GRUB) to are the same. Also, when installing Ubuntu, you should make sure that the bootloader is installed to the MBR of the HDD you want to use as a boot device in BIOS, not to one of its partitions.

If your computer is using (U)EFI, you must be careful to install both, Windows and Ubuntu in EFI mode (preferred), or both in BIOS compatibility mode (emergency solution, if EFI does not work). If you use BIOS compatibility mode, the pervious paragraph applies. If you use EFI mode, you might have to go to the EFI setup screen after installing Ubuntu, since both, Windows and Ubuntu, will create an EFI boot entry and on some computers EFI does not automatically switch to Ubuntu. The labeling is slightly misleading, since the Ubuntu entry actually launches a bootloader that allows you to choose every time you boot your PC, if you want to boot to Ubuntu or Windows.

Comment: Sorry but , i didn't really understand.

Answer (score 0):

This was the problem that I met days before.

If system directly loading into Ubuntu.

Update your Grub. Go to terminal then type

```
   sudo update-grub
```

then

```
   sudo reboot
```

Else you have any Graphics problem please mention it as camment.

Comment: OP said "_IT directly boots into Windows_".

Comment: In windows turn off Fast boot first.Then restart.

Comment: I run the BIOS->Advance, then i found :
1-Boot Speem  [Normal] , i put fast
2-Boot sound  [ON]
3-System ...  ; with have nothing important
-----------------------------------------------
I didn't find the "Fast Boot"

Comment: Not in BIOS.Fast boot in windows7.See  http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/6320-fast-startup-turn-off-windows-8-a.html